# Using SpringExtension with Tomcat and Hibernate web app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-test

We are trying to use spring-test's `SpringExtension` to write integration tests for our Spring and Hibernate-based Tomcat web application. Our `sessionFactory` bean configuration has the property configured `mappingJarLocations` with a sample value as `/WEB-INF/lib/company-common*.jar` which contains hibernate mapping files. In both actual deployment and Eclipse dev deployment, this works fine as the `docBasePath` (in Servlet environment) is appended to this pattern and the files are getting resolved. But this is not the case while running JUnit test cases either in a local or a CI environment.

We tried our best to use the provided support by having few overridden implementations of `WebTestContextBootstraper`, `GenricXmlWebContextLoader`, `XmlWebApplicationContext`, and `WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader` but had to finally give up as we cannot override the final method `org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(MergedContextConfiguration)` to provide the custom implementation of `XmlWebApplicationContext`. Our current approach is to manually create the application context and use it in the tests.

Here is the project structure:

```
Project_WebApp
|--src/**
|--WebContent/**
|--pom.xml
```

When the app is packaged as `Project_WebApp.war`, the dependencies are inside `WEB-INF/lib` from the root of extracted war. When deployed as a webapp in Tomcat using Eclipse, the dependencies are copied to `<Eclipse_Workspace_Dir>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/Project_WebApp/WEB-INF/lib`. In both cases, the dependencies are available at `<Resource_Base_Path>/WEB-INF/lib` and `Resource_Base_Path` has no relation to `Project_WebApp` base directory.

Questions:

- Did any one use SpringExtension in a scenario similar to above? If so can you suggest any alternative approaches?
- Instead of `/WEB-INF/lib/company-common*.jar`, we tried a classpath-based pattern but didn't work as the obtained class path resources don't match the pattern. Is there anything else to try here?

Comment: Without seeing your actual project, it's not really possible to say what a solution could look like. Is this all in a single project on disk? Are the JARs always present in `WEB-INF/lib`? Where is `WEB-INF/lib` in the file system relative to the root of your project? etc.

Comment: @SamBrannen Updated with project structure and additional info